# Print statement in Javascript (not to console)

Tags: javascript, html, input, printing

I am looking for a way to greet a user when they enter their name using a JavaScript app. The closest I have come is by using:

```js
function getname() {
  var number = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  alert("Hello, " + fname);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter name:<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="greet" onclick="getname()" />
</form>
```

which gives me a pop-up window displaying

> Hello, [objectHTMLInputElement]

However, I don't want to use a pop-up window, or even an HTML. I just want JavaScript to greet me using my name after it prompts me to enter one.

Comment: JavaScript in a web browser can use `alert()` or modify/create DOM elements. Those are your choices.

Comment: You've ruled out places where you want the message to appear, but you haven't told us where you *do* want the message to appear.

Comment: Or, when you said "I don't want to use … HTML" did you mean you wanted to run the JavaScript some other way? Such as with ASP Classic, Windows Scripting Host, Adobe Photoshop, or Node.js?

Comment: Yea as the above says, where do you want to see the message? Javascript can only use console.log, alert or modify the HTML DOM to send messages... In Node.js in a terminal window you can do a bit more but not in browser capable javascript...

Comment: I suppose you could use JavaScript to bellow the user's name through the computer speakers.

Comment: I thought there were apps built in Javascript that displayed a person's name when they signed in. Do these apps use HTML then? Is Javascript pretty much a support language?

Comment: What I'm getting from this is that JS does not have it's own I/O stream, unlike literally every other programming language I've ever seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've being using the wrong var inside getname() function...

instead using `fname` inside alert function you should use `number`, in my case I changed `number` to `string`

```js
function getname() {
  var string = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  alert("Hello, " + string);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter name:<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="greet" onclick="getname()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `[objectHTMLInputElement]` because you're alerting `fname` instead of the variable containing the name (`number`?).

If you want text to speech, you're going to need a library, such as [Responsive Voice](https://responsivevoice.org/):

```js
function getname() {
  var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  responsiveVoice.speak("Hello, " + name);
}
```

```html
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>

<form>
  Enter name:<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /><br/>
  <input type="button" value="greet" onclick="getname()" />
</form>
```